# Is it ok to close Realm instance after each query/write?

Tags: android, realm, rx-java

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to open/close Realm instances. We are using Realm in 3 places - App, Activities and Worker thread. However, it might be pretty cool to access data from Realm from any place. Thus, we wrapped all our Realm queries/writes in a Data Layer. Is it ok (from performance point of view) to do the following for every query (and similar on each write)?

```
try (Realm realm = getRealm()) {
    return realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Task.class).isNull("name")
    .findAllSorted("createdAt", Sort.DESCENDING));
}
```

How do you do something similar in async transaction? Are there better approaches? (We are using RxJava).

Thank you!

**EDIT:** After quick response from @christian-melchior we will use it like this:

```
try (Realm realm = getRealm()) {
    return realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(Task.class).isNull("name")
    .findAllSortedAsync("createdAt", Sort.DESCENDING));
}
```

**EDIT2:** We actually settled on this:

```
Realm realm = getRealm();
return realm.where(Task.class).isNull("name")
  .findAllSortedAsync("createdAt", Sort.DESCENDING)
  .asObservable()
  .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
  .first()
  .map(realmObjects -> {
      if (realmObjects.isEmpty()) {
          realm.close();
          return null;
      }
      List<Task> res = realm.copyFromRealm(realmObjects);
      realm.close();
      return res;
  });
```

Since we want our `onComplete` to be called after each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `copyFromRealm` will give you an in-memory copy of all the data, so as long as you are not loading huge lists, it should work fine. You will use more memory though, and there is a slight overhead in opening and closing Realms all the time.

One idea for controlling the Realm lifecycle can be seen here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

Also note you in many cases can use our async API if you are concerned about loading data on the UI thread: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries

Comment: Thank you! We will use the *Async methods (forgot to mention that in the example). Why Realm makes so hard updating objects (you need to be in transaction), that makes abstracting away from Realm implementation pretty tough? Any chance of removing the need for `close()` altogether?